# Pundit, Devise - Authorization with multiple devise models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, pundit

Setting up authorization for two separate Devise models in a Rails application. Only the current signed in medical_student should be able to edit or delete their profile. Other medical_students should be able to view other medical_students and regular users should be able to view their profile as well.

Here is my code:

**Policy**

```
class MedicalStudentProfilePolicy
 attr_reader :medical_student, :medical_student_profile

 def initialize(medical_student, medical_student_profile)
  @medical_student = medical_student
  @medical_student_profile = medical_student_profile
 end

 def edit?
  @medical_student_profile.medical_student_id == medical_student
 end

 def destroy?
  @medical_student_profile.medical_student_id == medical_student
 end
end
```

**Pundit User**

```
def pundit_user
 if medical_student_signed_in?
  @medical_student = current_medical_student
 elsif user_signed_in?
  @medical_student = MedicalStudent.find params[:medical_student_id]
 end
end
```

**Edit**

```
 def edit
  authenticate_medical_student!
  authorize @medical_student_profile, :edit?
 end
```

**View**

```
- if policy(@medical_student_profile).edit?
```

This works when logged in as a user, however current medical students are unable to edit their profiles. Any ideas?

Comment: Use roles instead of different "user" classes. https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify